# .ko file not being built when building kernel modules

Tags: c, linux, module, kernel, kernel-module

I am currently trying to learn how to make kernel modules from the 'Linux Device Drivers' book. I have the basic example typed out as follows:

```c
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/module.h>

MODULE_LICENSE("Dual BSD/GPL");

static int hello_init(void)
{
    printk(KERN_ALERT "Hello, world\n");
    return 0;
}

static void hello_exit(void)
{
    printk("Goodbye, cruel world\n");
}

module_init(hello_init);
module_exit(hello_exit);
```

and I am using the following makefile to compile the file above, `hello.c`

```
KERNELDIR := /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build
PWD := $(shell pwd)

default:
    $(MAKE) -C $(KERNELDIR) M=$(PWD) modules
```

When I run the make command, the console output is as follows:

```
make -C /lib/modules/5.13.0-40-generic/build M=/home/finlay/src/linux-drivers modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.13.0-40-generic'
  MODPOST /home/finlay/src/linux-drivers/Module.symvers
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.13.0-40-generic'
```

For some reason the only files which are created are the following:

- .Module.symvers.cmd
- .modules.order.cmd
- Module.symvers
- modules.order

None of the files created seems to specifically be about the hello.c file. What's very strange is that this same file was working initially to create the `hello.ko` file however it is no longer working. Any ideas as to why this is not working?

Comment: What tells it to make a module hello.ko based on hello.c?

Comment: The makefile for doing that is in the `/usr/src/linux-headers-5.13.0-40-generic/build` directory, I am calling that makefile from my own makefile.

As I said, it was working to make the .ko file initially, however, it is no longer working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have now found the solution, I removed some lines from the makefile as I believed them to be redundant as I thought that they were only used if you were directly invoking the makefile from the kernel build directory. The correct makefile is below.

```
ifneq ($(KERNELRELEASE),)

obj-m := hello.o

else

KERNELDIR := /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build
PWD := $(shell pwd)

default:
    $(MAKE) -C $(KERNELDIR) M=$(PWD) modules

endif
```